# Доделать функционал slick slider?

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на миниатюры менялось главное изображение слева.

```js
$('.cases__slider').slick({
  draggable: true,
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  speed: 700,
  infinite: true,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      arrows: false,
      dots: true
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<div class="cases__slide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img src="img/case1.jpg" alt="" class="cases__img img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 cases__info">
      <p class="cases__title">
        Знаки для ветеранов ГЖД.
      </p>
      <p class="cases__desc">
        Знаки для ветеранов ГЖД. Знак изготовлен по эскизу заказчика. Применялась технология штамповка с гальванизацией под золото и нанесением мягких эмалей. На аверсе 3D изображение, на реверсе установлена безопасная булавка для крепления на одежду.
      </p>
      <div class="cases__thumbnails">
        <a class="cases__trigger" href="#">
          <img src="img/case1m.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a class="cases__trigger" href="#">
          <img src="img/case12m.png" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cases__slide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img src="img/case1.jpg" alt="" class="cases__img img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 cases__info">
      <p class="cases__title">
        Значки для группы компаний "ВВК".
      </p>
      <p class="cases__desc">
        Был разработан дизайн значка с логотипом заказчика. Применялась технология штамповка с гальванизацией под серебро и нанесением мягких эмалей.
      </p>
      <div class="cases__thumbnails">
        <a class="cases__trigger" href="#">
          <img src="img/case1m.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a class="cases__trigger" href="#">
          <img src="img/case12m.png" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, что пример кода сильно помог бы

Comment: Но похоже, что надо просто перебить CSS Slider Syncing

Comment: Или тупо для слайда дописать JS меняющий картинку по клику и slick тут ни при чем

Comment: Добавил пример кода. 2 слайда-отдельно файлы миниатюр и отдельно развернутое изображение. 
Как  же тогда тупо для слайда дописать js картинку по клику? пример кода бы

Answer (score 0):

Получаем индекс изображения, по которому кликаем (ссылки, в данном случае), и с помощью метода slickGoTo переходим к нужному слайду.

```
$(".cases__thumbnails a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  cases__thumbnails_num = $(this).index();
  $('.cases__slider').slick('slickGoTo', cases__thumbnails_num);
})
```